# Can Jenkins detect when a new build is available on a Bamboo server?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bamboo

Can Jenkins detect when a new build is available on a Bamboo server?

What I want is to create a Jenkins job that checks a Bamboo server for a new build.   I want this job to run once per hour.

Then, other tests that I have on that Jenkins server will rely on that check passing in order for them to kick off.

If this is possible, what is the usual way of doing this?  The Bamboo server is internal and does not need authentication to see status of builds or get build resources.

If there is no plugin for this, I do see a RSS feed at this URI:  **/rss/createAllBuildsRssFeed.action?feedType=rssAll&buildKey=RELEASE**  .   What method would other Jenkins administrators use to read this feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.  [I wrote a Gradle unit test to run in Jenkins that can read the RSS feed in Bamboo](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5069075).

The real way to do it though, which didn't answer my question, is to add a post-build hook to either Subverison or Bamboo to send a HTTP get request to Jenkins, which notifies a job to run.